# Trying to set JAVA_HOME in ~/.bashrc

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, profile

I have added this line at the end of ~/.bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin/java
```

But when I execute `echo $JAVA_HOME`, I don't get anything as output, I expected "/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin/java".

Any idea?

OS: Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: If you type `source ~/.bashrc`, does it work?

Comment: Getting the obvious question out of the way: have you restarted bash / reloaded the rc file since making the change?

Comment: As a peripheral comment: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin/java` is not a good practice. Generally, JAVA_HOME is exported as the parent directory where java artifacts are installed. In your case, it would be: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07. Then, you can add the bin dir of $JAVA_HOME to your PATH, eg.  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 1):

Both `/etc/bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` are whats referred to as `non-login` files. Meaning they do not get sourced during a login shell unless called by `/etc/profile` or another file.

If `/etc/profile` calls it (as is typical) then if you want to test it in your current shell you have to either source it.

`/root: #> source .bashrc` (source with the command source)

`/root: # . .bashrc` (source with a period)

Or you have to instantiate a `login` shell by using su or sudo.

`/root: # su -` (the dash starts a login shell which will re-source login files)

`/root: # sudo su -` (using sudo to perform the switch user command)

and of course you could just re-login.

EDIT:

Typically though Java paths are not set using .bashrc they are set as separate scripts in the `/etc/profile.d` directory. At least on the enterprise distributions I use.

```
system1:/etc/profile.d # ll
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1438 Aug 30  2005 alljava.csh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1682 Jul 13  2005 alljava.sh

system1:/etc/profile.d # cat alljava.sh
if [ -x /usr/$__libdir/jvm/java/bin/java ] || [ -x /usr/$__libdir/jvm/java/bin/jre ] ; then
export JAVA_BINDIR=/usr/$__libdir/jvm/java/bin
export JAVA_ROOT=/usr/$__libdir/jvm/java
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/$__libdir/jvm/java
#....cut for brevity...
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable the change which you have performed on ~/.bashrc file, you need to execute the command mentioned in the ~/.bashrc file . For this you have to close the terminal and open it again.